# If $f(x+1)= -f(x-1)$, prove that the function f is a periodic function and its period is $4$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

I sure do know that I should arrive to the point where $f(x)= f(x+T)$. I've tried replacing $x+1=a$ but the problem seems to get more and more complicated.

Comment: This seems false, at least with the usual definition of "period of a function" as the "fundamental period": if $f$ is the constant zero function, there is *no* fundamental period.

Comment: @ClementC. I would say it is basically correct but to be precise one should say than 4 is a period rather that asserting it is the period.

Comment: $f(x+1)=-f(x-1)=-f(x-2+1)=f(x-3)$. So $4$ is a period. It is not true that it is necessarily the shortest period.

Comment: @quid Yes -- just meant to point out that saying "its period" can be misleading.

Comment: Presumably that relation is supposed to hold _for all $x\in\Bbb R$_ (this is not clearly stated). It becomes a bit more transparent if you write that relation as $f(a)=-f(a-2)$ for all $a\in\Bbb R$, which is exactly the result of replacing $x+1=a$, as you suggested in the question. I don't see how this makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** fix any $y$, and apply your hypothesis to both $x\stackrel{\rm def}{=} y+1$ and $x'\stackrel{\rm def}{=} y+3$.

**In detail:** *(place your mouse over the grey areas to reveal the contents)*

Fix any $y\in\mathbb{R}$, and let $x\stackrel{\rm def}{=} y+1$, $x'\stackrel{\rm def}{=} y+3$.

> $$ f(y) = f(x-1) \stackrel{\rm (assumption)}{=} -f(x+1) = -f(y+2) $$

while

> $$ f(y+2) = f(x'-1) \stackrel{\rm (assumption)}{=} -f(x'+1) = -f(y+4)$$

so combining the two,

> $$ f(y) = -f(y+2) = f(y+4) $$

and since this holds for any $y$, $4$ is **a** period of $f$. (I.e., $f$ is $4$-periodic. There may be other periods.)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Start by trying to evaluate $f(x+4)$ and using the functional equation multiple times:

**Full solution:**

> $$\begin{align*}f(x+4) &= f(x+ 3 + 1)\\&=-f(x+3-1)\\&= -f(x+2)\\&=-f(x+1+1)\\&=-(-f(x+1-1))\\&= f(x)\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y:=x-1$ shows that
$$f(y+2)=-f(y)=-(-f(y-2))=f(y-2),$$
holds for all $y$, or equivalently $f(y+4)=f(y)$, so 'its period' is *at most* $4$.

As others have noted, it can be rather ambigious to speak of *the* period of a function. Such a function $f$ may have period $4$, but it may also have other (shorter) periods. And for some functions $f$ it is not clear what is meant by 'its' period, for example $f=0$. So I would rather say that we have shown that *$4$ is a period of $f$*.